# Sitemap specified in robots.txt not found by Google

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, robots.txt

I would like Google to find my *sitemap.xml* via *robots.txt*, rather than having to manually upload it.

My *[robots.txt](https://www.recreyo.com/robots.txt)* looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: https://www.recreyo.com/sitemap.xml
```

I've done the following:

- Checked via Google Webmaster Tools that *robots.txt* validates correctly
- Checked that *Sitemap.xml* validates correctly (via Add/Test SiteMap)
- Verified that a Googlebot has paid a visit to the site

However, in Google Webmaster Tools > Crawl > Sitemaps it says "No sitemaps found for this site."

The links listed in my sitemap.xml are not being indexed, while the landing page and related links *are* being indexed correctly.

How do I get Google to read my Sitemap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained in this Google reference](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2409931?hl=en), the sitemaps listed in the robots.txt are not displayed in the Google Webmaster Tools.

> Was your Sitemap submitted using ping or robots.txt? Only Sitemaps submitted using Webmaster Tools are listed on the Sitemaps page. To make sure your Sitemap information is visible, it's a good idea to use Webmaster Tools to submit your Sitemap for the first time, and then use ping or robots.txt to update it.

But this doesn't mean that Google is not taking them into consideration.

In fact, it's likely that if you add the sitemap directly in your GWT account in a few hours it will show that most of the URLs listed in the sitemaps are correctly indexed.

The only way to show them in your control panel is to add them manually.

Comment: thanks for the link. That explains a lot; I had assumed that "By Me" meant manual and All would have those from robots.txt. Let me give that a shot and get back.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to remove this message, as well as add your sitemap to Google - is to submit your sitemap. In Google Webmaster Tools click Crawl -> Sitemaps -> ADD/TEST SITEMAP.